# Dynamically fetching records from the database with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, dynamic, records

I wish to implement a web architecture where the all the table data will not be fetched in one go instead few records will be fetched and when the user scrolls down, the front end should again hit the database for the next set of records. How do I implement this? I have first part in Java where all the table data is fetched in one go.

Comment: use javascript ajax to loaad data

Comment: I have done it using javascript ajax. Thanks @Raghavendra

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with pagination in the queries :

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1). As you go on scrolling below you can increment the offset by 1 for each scroll or something like that :

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15 (offset : 5 , no of rows : 10)
```

You can refer this link as well for more details : [Effective pagination using MySql](http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/view?login=Eweaver&preview=no&slideid=1&title=efficient-pagination-using-mysql)